# change the python matplotlib colormap dynamic range for certain range

Tags: python, dynamic, matplotlib, range, colormap

I have created a 2D gaussian function for display, the variable gauss (below) is in range of (0, 1). what I want to do is change the default colormap  dynamic range from (black, white) to (gray, white)

```
gauss = np.exp( -(((Xm**2)+(Ym**2)) / (2.0* s**2)) )
p=plt.imshow(gauss, 'Greys_r')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the color maps `Greys_r` in conjunction with the parameters `vmin=0.25` and `vmax=1.`.

```
from matplotlib import cm

p = plt.imshow(gauss, cmap=cm.Greys_r, vmin=025, vmax=1.)
```

Comment: 3Q, but I want to shrink the range rather than invert it.

Comment: ^_^, have checked. I'm new to stack.